# How to display only the contents of the workspace in a TreeViewer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to display only the contents of the workspace in my `TreeViewer`?

This is my main view class:

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class MainView extends ViewPart {
    public static final String ID = "com.MainView";

    public MainView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        TreeViewer tv = new TreeViewer(parent);
        tv.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        tv.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
        tv.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
        tv.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace());
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is my content provider class:

```java
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;

public class FileTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    public void dispose() {

    }

    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {

    }

    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return null;
    }

    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        if (parentElement instanceof IProject) {
            IProject projects = (IProject) parentElement;
            try {
                return projects.members();
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (parentElement instanceof IFolder) {
            IFolder ifolder = (IFolder) parentElement;
            try {
                return ifolder.members();
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof IProject) {
            IProject projects = (IProject) element;
            return projects.getParent();
        }
        if (element instanceof IFolder) {
            IFolder folder = (IFolder) element;
            return folder.getParent();
        }
        if (element instanceof IFile) {
            IFile file = (IFile) element;
            return file.getParent();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof IProject) {
            IProject projects = (IProject) element;
            try {
                return projects.members().length > 0;
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (element instanceof IFolder) {
            IFolder folder = (IFolder) element;
            try {
                return folder.members().length > 0;
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my label provider class:

```java
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;

public class FileTreeLabelProvider implements ILabelProvider {

    public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {

    }

    public void dispose() {

    }

    public boolean isLabelProperty(Object element, String property) {

        return false;
    }

    public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {

    }

    public Image getImage(Object element) {

        return null;
    }

    public String getText(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof IProject) {
            String text = ((IProject) element).getName();
            return text;
        }
        if (element instanceof IFolder) {
            String text = ((IFolder) element).getName();
            return text;
        }
        if (element instanceof IFile) {
            String text = ((IFile) element).getName();
            return text;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code do? What works/what doesn't? Does it throws an exception? Does it return empty? Hard to spot an issue if we don't know what happens.

Comment: the code returns null..im not sure how to use the IFolder to get the folders and IFiles to get the files..

Comment: http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-11-common-navigator-displaying-custom-resources-or-refresh-or-die-or-the-magic-of-navigatorcontent/                                   I Found this site it shows how to use resources to get the workspace but does not tell about using folders .if i want to use the folders i need the file Ipath.But i dont have the ipath value.I am able to get the raw location however its not helping.

Comment: Hey Zoltan ive uploaded my revised code

Comment: Why do you call tv.setInput with a string, shouldn't this be your workspace object? Your content provider does not check for strings. Also why do you check for an instanceof a workspace in your content provider, ignore it and get it from ResourcesPlugin? I would normally expect a call to tv.setInput with ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() instead.

Comment: ya Simon i had corrected that .What should i call in my getElements method or how should my getElemts method look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
    }
```

I am able to get projects now.my code is working

Answer (score 0):

A content provider and a label provider for the workspace objects are already present in the Eclipse framework:

- [`org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchLabelProvider`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/model/WorkbenchLabelProvider.html)
- [`org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/model/WorkbenchContentProvider.html)

Using them, your code will look like this:

```java
TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent);
treeViewer.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
treeViewer.setContentProvider(new WorkbenchContentProvider());
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
```